# Jquery / Javascript error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am getting the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" in javascript.

I took some original code by, Paul Da Silva, and modified it. I am changing from a datePicker into a timePicker.  I have renamed some fields and functions, and am still debugging it. But I did something wrong / broke something in the process.  I ran it thru jLint and fixed some of the minor issues.  I am stumped, can someone help?

The error occurs on the following line

```
this.bindMethodsToObj("show", "hide", "hideIfClickOutside", "keydownHandler", "selectTime");
```

but the functions: "bindMethodsToObj", "show", "hide", "hideIfClickOutside", "keydownHandler", "selectTime" all exist?

Line 534:

```
bindMethodsToObj: function () {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this[arguments[i]] = this.bindToObj(this[arguments[i]]);
    }
},
```

The test html page is at: http://www.gleneck.com/tv/_vhslibr14/jtpicker/jtpicker_test.htm

the javascript is at: www.gleneck.com/tv/_vhslibr14/jtpicker/jquery.jtpicker.js

I am stumped, can someone help?

Comment: Chrome's debugger reveals a little more information: `Object #<a jtPicker> has no method 'bindMethodsToObj'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 88 of your jquery.jtpicker.js needs to be changed from:

```
jtPicker.R_o_w_type = {
```

to:

```
jtPicker.prototype = {
```

The prototype method is how javascript knows to add those functions to your object. It doesn't know what to do with "R_o_w_type"

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript file, I think that line 88:

```
jtPicker.R_o_w_type = {
```

... should probably look like:

```
jtPicker.prototype = {
```

so that it actually adds the methods to the function.

It looks like there's some other stuff to figure out, but that should correct your issue.